# Get list of files from Apache index page using Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to create a radar animation using data from the National Weather Service. For static images they make it easy by always having the same filename. However, for the historical images, they are timestamped, and always change. Thus, to get the previous N images, you would have to know the filenames beforehand. They do, however, provide a directory which provides a listing for each site. See the example here:
http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/FWS/

What I need is from my Rails app to extract the last N images from that directory. Is that possible? I could imagine one option would be to download and then scrape that page, but I am assuming there is a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you written to solve this? We need to see that, along with a description of errors received or how its failing to do what you wrote. Without that, your question will likely be considered "Not a real question."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from the above you could try something like I just tried in the console..

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'    
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/FWS/'))
doc.xpath('//table/tr/td').each do |tabrow|
  puts tabrow.content
end
```

That's a pretty basic stab in the dark but should give you food for thought to get you on the way

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to download them using a library like `curb`, parse the page with something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) and then combine the images using whatever tool works best for you.

Rails is designed to handle web requests, not run as a background job, but there are tools that can facilitate this for you or you can always make scripts for `rails runner` to execute in the Rails environment.